# "dir"-Input RTL but with LTR measurement data | "فثسف 3 cm فثسف" should be (فثسفy 3 cm فثسف)

Tags: javascript, html, arabic, right-to-left

Do someone know if this is an issue of the browser, the windows language or something in general?

I installed on my computer a second language called "Arabic (Saudi Arabia) Arabic (101) keyboard".

[image: German (Germany) and Arabic (Saudi Arabia) keyboards]

And if I enter a text like "test 3cm test" (for "3cm" I switch to German keyboard) its more or less correct. - with `dir="rtl"`.

[image: RTL sentence]

When I'm using `ltr` as `dir` it looks like when I'm copy&pasting it here.

فثسف 3cm فثسف

And now the (main) question.
When I add a space between `3` and `cm` it will be vice versa.

[image: RTL sentence]

Do you know if it's possible to handle it with JavaScript or HTML like my picture modification below?

[image: This is how it should look like]

Or is it a language behaviour?

Thanks in Advance! :-)

What did I tried?

1. Using `auto` in `dir`

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<body>
  <input type="text" dir="auto" style="text-align: left;" value="فثسف 3 cm فثسف" />
</body>
</html>
```

And this.

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<body>
  <input type="text" dir="auto" style="text-align: right;" value="فثسف 3 cm فثسف" />
</body>
</html>
```

The `value` comes from this workflow.

1. Switch to Arabic (RTL language)
2. Write "test "
3. Switch to German (LTR language)
4. Write "3 cm "
5. Switch to Arabic (RTL language)
6. Write "test"
7. Strg + A in the Input and put it into `value="STRG + V"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you mind editing your question to include what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] and include the relevant HTML & CSS in your question. It shouldn't be a problem, probably you need to set the following CSS  `direction:rtl; text-align: right;` to the relevant element

Comment: Yes I'll do in few minutes :-) Thanks for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @alex-cohn idea with [`&lrm;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) and [`&rlm;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) tags and developed something what I need

```js
var ltrMarkThere = false;
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keydown", function testKey(e) {
  if(e.key.match(/[0-9]/)) {
    document.getElementById("test").value += "\u202a";
    ltrMarkThere = true;
  } else if(ltrMarkThere && e.key.charCodeAt(0) > 127) {
    document.getElementById("test").value = document.getElementById("test").value.replace(/( ?)$/, "\u202c$1");
    ltrMarkThere = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="test" type="text" style="direction: rtl; text-align: right;" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" value="فثسف ‪3 cm‬ فثسف" />
    <!-- There is a hidden UTF8 Right-to-left-mark and hidden UTF8 Left-to-right-mark which allows to have it like this  -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good. I could nitpick that not all characters above 127 are RTL, or that you don't need four LRMs for `"1234"`. But no doubt, your snippet implements my concept.

Comment: Ah yes @AlexCohn you're right. I need a `!ltrMarkThere` in the first `if` so that I have only one &LRM; for `"1234"`  But no thats then not working when someone deletes the 1234 and the system think the mark is there and then its not set again 

Answer (score 3):

The question is how far you are ready to go. You can wrap `3 cm` with `<span>` tag and then it will be layed out independent of everything around it,

```html
<div dir="rtl">فثسف <span dir="ltr">3 cm</span> فثسف</div>
```

Or you can insert `&lrm;` and `&rlm;`, or some direction-override chracters:

```html
<div dir="rtl">فثسف &lrm;3 cm&rlm; فثسف</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but we are talking about an `<input />` which not supports things like you did. So I can do everything with Javascript like set cursor and this things but nothing else. With your `<div />` solution it would work, thats true.

Comment: With JavaScript, you can inject characters into input, so the second approach may work

Comment: Looks really great. Now I must find a way how to realize something like "If number is entered add this Left-to-right-mark and if no `[ cm]` is added then remove it or add Right-to-left-mark.

Comment: You can keep the LRM, it won't harm if compensate by RLM. Actually, you probably don't need RLM at all!

Comment: You can check my own answer post here. I added a keydown event which adds the needed mark and then it looks like I want 